# How to run code only inside javascript function?

Tags: javascript, ajax, function, attributes

I'm trying with ajax to send innerhtml. Some attributes must be deleted before sending. When I click the buttton I delete the attributes and send..., and everything works fine, but my attributes are deleted in html as well.

They should only be deleted within the function and sent, but should not be deleted in html!
HOW TO AVOID IT.

Code:

```
<div id="container" class="container" >

    <div id="parent1" class="parent">
         <div id="child1" class="child" ondrop="drop(event);" ondragover="allowDrop(event);" >same content</div>
    </div>

    <div id="parent2" class="parent">
         <div id="child2" class="child" ondrop="drop(event);" ondragover="allowDrop(event);" >same content</div>
    </div>

    <div id="parent3" class="parent">
         <div id="child3" class="child" ondrop="drop(event);" ondragover="allowDrop(event);" >same content</div>
    </div>

</div>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
```

```
function myFunction() {
  var divsclass = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName("parent"));

  var parenthtml = "";
  divsclass.forEach(function(div){
    Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".parent [ondrop]")).forEach((elem) => elem.removeAttribute("ondrop"));
    Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".parent [ondragover]")).forEach((elem) => elem.removeAttribute("ondragover"));
    var parenthtmlsend = div.innerHTML;
    parenthtml += "&PARENTHTML"+ n++ +"=" + parenthtmlsend;
  });

    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {

            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "same-page.php? "+ encodeURI(results) + parenthtml, true);
        xmlhttp.send();

}
```

I tried copying the code to another div and then deleting atributes, but even then the attributes in the html code were deleted.

```
    var containercopy = document.getElementById("container").innerHTML;
    document.getElementById("container-copy").innerHTML = containercopy;
```

My code is big so I rewrote and give a brief example, maybe along the way I made a mistake ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure this is good way, but you can clone **deeply** your element in array and then do your changes with it.

see the code

```js
function myFunction() {
  var divsclass = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName("parent")); 
   
  var parenthtml = "";
  
  divsclass.forEach(function(div){
    
    // clone
    var clonedDiv = div.cloneNode(true);;
    
    Array.from(clonedDiv.querySelectorAll(".parent [ondrop]")).forEach((elem) =>                              elem.removeAttribute("ondrop"));
    Array.from(clonedDiv.querySelectorAll(".parent [ondragover]")).forEach((elem) =>                          elem.removeAttribute("ondragover"));
    var parenthtmlsend = clonedDiv.innerHTML;
    parenthtml += "&PARENTHTML"+ n++ +"=" + parenthtmlsend;
  });

    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {

            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "same-page.php? "+ encodeURI(results) + parenthtml, true);
        xmlhttp.send();

}
```

It seems in your code `n` is undefined, but i didn't change it

Comment: Some other way. When I delete attributes to delete in function but not in HTML

Comment: My bad. Try to use ```div.querySelectorAll``` instead of ```document.querySelectorAll```, I updated my answer

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I replaced but still delete everything in html...

Comment: You use deepclone and div.querySelectorAll and it doesn't work? I'll try to test

Comment: It really doesn't work with lodash clone, have no idea why. But we have another way: use ```element.cloneNode(true)```, I updated my answer again

Comment: I get queryselectorall is undefined. n is left of the original code if I have reduced it to explain in the example...

Comment: OK! I think it works I have to check all functions and whether it properly deletes attributes and sends via ajax..., and replay after check..., thx

Comment: Try this codepen https://codepen.io/grumaks/pen/GRJxKpe I removed ```n++``` and change ajax call for ```console.log()```. It works for me

Comment: Thank you. It works fine except after deleting some attributes it stops doing click () elements, I try to figure out why, I don't get any eror ...